# Unknown number of child and grandchild elements in an XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have loaded a number of large XML files into an XML field/table in my MSSQL database.  My table (called XMLImport) has two columns; an ID column and a second column labeled XMLColumn for the XML file.  I now need to get certain elements out of that data so that it can be loaded into various places in the database. I have included the basic format of my XML files below.  The number of elements, subelements and subsubelements varies with each file.

```
<root>
  <data1>apples</data1>
  <data2>pears</data2>
  <data3>coconuts</data3>   
  <element1>
    <data1>white</data1>
    <data2>brown</data2>
    <data3>green</data3>
    <data4>yellow</data4>
    <data5>blue</data5>
    <subelement1>
        <data1>one</data1>
        <data2>two</data2>
        <data3>three</data3>
        <data4>four</data4>         
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>name1</data1>
            <data2>slow</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
        <subsubelement2>
            <data1>name2</data1>
            <data2>fast</data2>
        </subsubelement2>
    </subelement1>
    <subelement2>
        <data1>five</data1>
        <data2>six</data2>
        <data3>seven</data3>
        <data4>eight</data4>    
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>name3</data1>
            <data2>fast</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
    </subelement2>
  </element1>
  <element2>
    <data1>red</data1>
    <data2>pink</data2>
    <data3>purple</data3>
    <data4>black</data4>
    <subelement1>
        <data1>nine</data1>
        <data2>ten</data2>
        <data3>eleven</data3>
        <data4>twelve</data4>           
    </subelement1>
    <subelement2>
        <data1>thirteen</data1>
        <data2>fourteen</data2>
        <data3>fifteen</data3>
        <data4>sixteen</data4>  
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>name1</data1>
            <data2>fast</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
    </subelement2>
  </element2>
  <element3>
    <data1>text</data1>
    <data2>text</data2>
    <data3>text</data3>
    <data4>text</data4>
    <data5>text</data5>
    <subelement1>
        <data1>text</data1>
        <data2>text</data2>
        <data3>text</data3>
        <data4>text</data4>         
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>text</data1>
            <data2>text</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
    </subelement1>
  </element3>
</root>
```

I need to be able to generate output like this:

```
apples | pears | white | brown | two | name1 | slow
apples | pears | white | brown | two | name2 | fast
apples | pears | white | brown | six | name3 | fast
apples | pears | red   | pink  | ten | name1 | fast
etc.
```

I need to get data from the subsubelement level regardless of how many subsubelements there are under one subelement.  And then I need to move on to the next subelement and do the same.  And then move on to the next element in the data and repeat.  Here is my current query.

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
SELECT XMLColumn.value('(/root/data1)[1]','varchar(150)') AS FirstColumn,
       XMLColumn.value('(/root/data2)[1]','varchar(150)') AS SecondColumn,
       XMLColumn.value('(/root/element1/data1)[1]','varchar(150)') AS ThirdColumn,
       XMLColumn.value('(/root/element1/data2)[1]','varchar(150)') AS FourthColumn,
       XMLColumn.value('(/root/element1/subelement1/data2)[1]','varchar(150)') AS FifthColumn,
       XMLColumn.value('(/root/element1/subelement1/subsubelement1/data1)[1]','varchar(150)') AS SixthColumn,
       XMLColumn.value('(/root/element1/subelement1/subsubelement1/data2)[1]','varchar(150)') AS SeventhColumn
FROM dbo.XMLImport
```

If I change the [1] to another number I can get the next value at that level but I can't get more than one.  Is there a way for me to loop through this data?  Any assistance is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: In your real XML: Are the elements really numbered (data1,data2, ...)?

Comment: @Shnugo - No, my data is classified I was just trying to make something up that would show how many layers I have and the variability.  I don't have any experience with XML.  I am an SQL programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this, but - to be honest - I have no idea how you want to put this *side-by-side*...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
  <data1>apples</data1>
  <data2>pears</data2>
  <data3>coconuts</data3>   
  <element1>
    <data1>white</data1>
    <data2>brown</data2>
    <data3>green</data3>
    <data4>yellow</data4>
    <data5>blue</data5>
    <subelement1>
        <data1>one</data1>
        <data2>two</data2>
        <data3>three</data3>
        <data4>four</data4>         
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>name1</data1>
            <data2>slow</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
        <subsubelement2>
            <data1>name2</data1>
            <data2>fast</data2>
        </subsubelement2>
    </subelement1>
    <subelement2>
        <data1>five</data1>
        <data2>six</data2>
        <data3>seven</data3>
        <data4>eight</data4>    
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>name3</data1>
            <data2>fast</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
    </subelement2>
  </element1>
  <element2>
    <data1>red</data1>
    <data2>pink</data2>
    <data3>purple</data3>
    <data4>black</data4>
    <subelement1>
        <data1>nine</data1>
        <data2>ten</data2>
        <data3>eleven</data3>
        <data4>twelve</data4>           
    </subelement1>
    <subelement2>
        <data1>thirteen</data1>
        <data2>fourteen</data2>
        <data3>fifteen</data3>
        <data4>sixteen</data4>  
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>name1</data1>
            <data2>fast</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
    </subelement2>
  </element2>
  <element3>
    <data1>text</data1>
    <data2>text</data2>
    <data3>text</data3>
    <data4>text</data4>
    <data5>text</data5>
    <subelement1>
        <data1>text</data1>
        <data2>text</data2>
        <data3>text</data3>
        <data4>text</data4>         
        <subsubelement1>
            <data1>text</data1>
            <data2>text</data2>
        </subsubelement1>
    </subelement1>
  </element3>
</root>';
```

--The query

```
SELECT  lvl1.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue1
       ,lvl2.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue2
       ,lvl3.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue3
       ,lvl4.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue4
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/*') AS A(lvl1)
OUTER APPLY lvl1.nodes('*') AS B(lvl2)
OUTER APPLY lvl2.nodes('*') AS C(lvl3)
OUTER APPLY lvl3.nodes('*') AS D(lvl4)
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try.  I don't really need things displayed in a row I need to be able to load them into a row in a table.  I was just trying to show that some of the fields in one row would need to be the same for another row if there were multiple subsubelements.